# Why don't you include auto capitalization in the starting of a sentence?

Tags: feature-request, editor

In Microsoft Word, I have found that there is no need to make the first letter of the word of a sentence capital, because they make it capital automatically when we put a space after the first word.

Why don't you introduce such a feature in all your sites ?

Comment: Is it *really* that hard to press the Shift key?

Comment: @OneKitten Oh. No. I was just suggesting it.

Comment: Because it would be so annoying.

Answer (score 15):

> jQuery has a tendency to do this thing that I need to ask about.

There are some instances where auto capitalization makes no sense. Also, we expect our users to show some level of effort. The next stage would be to automatically ask questions for the user as well? :)

Comment: (Pssst, though I couldn't agree more: I don't think that Word would auto-capitalize text that already includes some capital?)

Comment: Not sure. But there are also names which don't have any capitals at all on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

One reason not to do that: as far as I know, [the automatic quality filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers) also take these things into account. When auto-correcting lazy question askers before they post their question, then that part of the filter won't work anymore.

(And in general I don't like site-specific "enhancements". If I need some specific behaviour, then I search for a browser extension that works the same on all sites I visits.)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (somebool)
    doSomething();
```

The above code doesn't work. I have tried.. etc.

---

Since a lot of the languages we use on Stack Overflow are case sensitive, questions like the example above would be capitalised incorrectly. I expect we'd have lots of `You've got a capital I` type answers from new / infrequent users.